# Скрипт для перевода файла Excel в базу данных MySQL

Tags: php, excel, mysql

Ищу готовое решение для перевода файлов `excel` в базу данных `MySql` через скрипт `php`. База в `excel` состоит из 5 колонок. Скрипт должен перегонять данные в готовую таблицу. 
Подскажите готовое решение или посоветуйте, как реализовать такой скрипт. Если можно, отвечать, только если сами пользуетесь такими. В интернете много скриптов, но все они очень криво работают.

Answer (score 1):

Пользуемся поиском: [вопросы по меткам excel & php](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel&php/).

Comment: и что там по предложенной ссылке? сами-то сходили по ней?